# Alternative to IsNullOrEmpty for nullable types?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

Is there a way to use `IsNullOrEmpty` with nullable types? The code above generates a build error when using `IsNullOrEmpty` with `string? RunDate`

```
    public int MyMethod(string? RunDate = null)
    {

        string sql = string.Empty;
        int rowsChanged = -1;
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(RunDate))
        {
            //do stuff
        }
     }
```

Comment: Unless you're currently using C# 8 preview, `?` isn't legal to use with reference types. Has nothing to do with IsNullOrEmpty. `?` is strictly allowed to be used with value types before C# 8.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen I'd pay to see that C# 8 preview working on VS 2010, according to the tags :)

Comment: Well, clever people have hacked visual studio before, I wouldn't put it past them.

Comment: Does anyone know why I was given 2 downvotes?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are intending to use `?` like in TypeScript where it implies an optional value; but this is not the case in C#.  In C#, The `T?` syntax is shorthand for `Nullable<T>`.  The `Nullable<T>` struct has a constraint on `T` such `T` must also be a struct.  `System.String`, is a `class` and not a `struct`, so it cannot be used with `Nullable<T>`.

The purpose of `Nullable<T>` is to contain a either a value of type `T` OR `null`, since `struct` based values cannot be null references themselves.  All `class` based values can already contain null references, so it doesn't make sense to use them with `Nullable<T>`.

Try rewriting your code like this:

```
public int MyMethod(string RunDate = null)
    {

        string sql = string.Empty;
        int rowsChanged = -1;
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(RunDate))
        {
            //do stuff
        }
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

It must be `string? RunDate = null` this line. You don't need to declare string as nullable type `string?` since `string` by itself is a reference type and thus defaults to `null`. It can simply be

```
public int MyMethod(string RunDate = null)
{
   // rest of code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Quick answer, no.

Longer answer, not yet.

Right now, before C# 8 is released (well, as long as you're not using C# 8 preview that is), the `?` symbol when used to specify  nullable reference types, is a syntax error. Let's ignore C# 8 for the time being.

`type?` is translated to `Nullable<type>`, and the `Nullable<T>` struct is declared like this:

```
public struct Nullable<T> where T : struct
```

In other words, `T` cannot be `string`, so this, `string?`, is not legal. This is what is giving you the syntax error.

Until C# 8 is released, or you start using C# 8 Preview, there is nothing you can do, except remove the question mark.

---

What happens when C# 8 is released?

Well, `type?` for *reference types* **will not** translate to `Nullable<T>` but instead to `T` with knowledge about the nullability. For fields, properties, parameters, return types, basically anything that isn't a local variable, this will translate into a declaration with an attribute stating the nullability. For local variables the compiler will keep track of the nullability.

So in this case, `string.IsNullOrEmpty` will in fact work because the parameter will still fundamentally be a string, it will just be a string with the knowledge of nullability attached to it.

Comment: Now, will this be supported by Visual Studio 2010? No, it will not. You might be able to trick the compiler into using the right version, but intellisense will be borked and there is nothing you can do about that except upgrade.

Answer (score -2):

The `?` operator is used to declare non-nullable types as nullable, and the compiler compiles them to be of type `Nullable<T>`.

The `System.String` is a reference type thus is nullable.

Remove the `?` operator and things should work.

Comment: @AviMeltser It's *not* redundant.  That's not a fact.  For it to be redundant it would need to be equivalent to not doing it, and it's not, because it errors, so that *does* stand against it.